# Is there a particular use case for fold() function

Tags: collections, language-agnostic, pipeline, theory

When accumulating a collection (just collection, not list) of values into a single value, there are two options.

1. `reduce()`. Which takes a `List<T>`, and a function `(T, T) -> T`, and applies that function iteratively until the whole list is reduced into a single value.
2. `fold()`. Which takes a `List<T>`, an initial value `V`, and a function `(V, T) -> V`, and applies that function iteratively until the whole list is folded into a single value.

I know that both of them have their own use cases. For eg, `reduce()` can be used to find maximum value in a list and `fold()` can be used to find sum of all values in a list.

But, in that example, instead of using `fold()`, you can `add(0)`, and then `reduce()`. Another use case of fold is to join all elements into a string. But this can also be done without using fold, by `map |> toString()` followed by `reduce()`.

Just out of curiosity, the question is, can every use case of `fold()` be avoided given functions `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()` and `add()`? (also `remove()` if required.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around.  `reduce(L,f) = fold(first(L), rest(L), f)`, so there's no special need for `reduce` -- it's just a short form for a common `fold` pattern.

`fold` has lots of use cases of its own, though.

The example you gave for string concatenation is one of them -- you can fold items into a special string accumulator much more efficiently than you can build strings by incremental accumulation. (exactly how depends on the language, but it's true pretty much everywhere).

Applying a list of incremental changes to a target object is a pretty common pattern.  Adding files to a folder, drawing shapes on a canvas, turning a list into a set, crossing off completed items in a to-do list, etc., are all examples of this pattern.

Also `map(L,f) = fold(newMap(), L, (M,v) -> add(M,f(v))`, so `map` is also just a common `fold` pattern.  Similarly, `filter(L,f) = fold(newList(), L, (L,v) -> f(v) ? add(L,v) : L)`.

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning how `fold` can mimic `map` and `reduce` operations also.